# GAE - Google Endpoints with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I've tried integrate de Endpoints with Cloud SQL and Hibernate.
But, everytime a have a error.
Follow my tests:

1 - persistence.xml in source folder:
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/24WQc.jpg
  Give-me the error:
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIPCi.jpg

2 - persistence.xml in resources folder give me the error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named gegAdminPU
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
>       at br.com.gegsystems.gegadmin.utils.HibernateUtils.(HibernateUtils.java:47)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
>       at br.com.gegsystems.gegadmin.endpoints.ClienteEndpoint.(ClienteEndpoint.java:20)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.getClassForName(ServletInitializationParameters.java:82)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.fromServletConfig(ServletInitializationParameters.java:51)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.init(SystemServiceServlet.java:102)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Follow the Endpoint code:

```
@Api(name="clientes", version="v1")
public class ClienteEndpoint {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    static {
        entityManagerFactory = HibernateUtils.getEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @ApiMethod(name="listar", path="clientes")
    public List<String> listar(){
        List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT 'teste' FROM dual;");
        resultado.add((String) query.getSingleResult());

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

HibernateUtils.java:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver;
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

public class HibernateUtils {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    static {
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
                SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",
                    "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getProperty(
                    "jdbc:google:mysql://**********:*******/gegadmin?user=root")
            );
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password",
                    System.getProperty("**********"));
        } else {
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class",
                    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", System.getProperty(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gegadmin?user=root")
            );
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.password",
                    System.getProperty("**********"));
        }

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("gegAdminPU", properties);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem, where System.getProperty("whatever") returns null when called from an endpoint stack, but it works if called through a servlet; I don't know if it's related, but it may be worth checking out

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed the persistence framework from Hibernate to EclipseLink and work. I think that was a problem in the configuration of my Eclipse with Hibernate and JPA.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the persistence framework from Hibernate to EclipseLink and work. 
I think that was a problem in the configuration of my Eclipse with Hibernate and JPA.